# Как лучше исправить foreach цикл, внутри которого расширяется перебираемая коллекция?

Tags: c#, foreach

Коллекция выглядит так:

```
public class myList : List<myClass> { }
```

Мне нужно повторять цикл до тех пор, пока он добавляет новые элементы:

```
do {
    newObjectAdded = false;
    foreach (myClass obj in myList) {
        //...
        if (some_condition) {
            myList.Add(newObj); 
            newObjectAdded = true;}
        //...
    }
} while (newObjectAdded);
```

После того, как в лист добавится элемент, в строке `foreach (myClass obj in myList)` я получаю ошибку - коллекция была изменена, невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления.

Можно заменить `foreach` на цикл с итератором, но от этого обращение к объектам станет довольно громоздким. Ещё есть вариант с заменой списка на LinkedList, но это ещё хуже, в данном случае.

Существует ли какой-то более элегантный способ?

Comment: @InfernumDeus, не знаю тонкостей шарпа, но выполнять foreach на изменяемой коллекции - это не очень хороший подход. Лучше изменить на

    while (промежуточноеХранилище.length > 0) {
        var x = промежуточноеХранилище.pop();
    }

и обновлять это промежуточное хранилище, докидывая элементы в конец.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сам разобрался.
Достаточно написать:

```
foreach (myClass obj in myList.ToArray()) {
```

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как верный.

Comment: Вообще, не стоит использовать это решение. Следует подумать получше и применить отдельную временную коллекцию.